# Google Maps API Returning marker position to hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to get users to mark their places, I am using this code below to get user's postcode and zoom into their neighbourhood but I couldn't figure out how to get marker coordinates.

I have seen some examples with actionlisteners like this one below but it did not work.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker,
        'drag',
        function() {
            document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.position.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.position.lng();
        }
    );



    var localSearch;
    var map;
    var icon;
    var addressMarkerOptions;
    google.load("search", "1");
    google.load("maps", "2");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function initialize()
    {
      localSearch = new GlocalSearch();
      icon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
      addressMarkerOptions = { icon:icon , map: map ,draggable: true};
      map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      plotAddress("M13 0JN");
    }

    /**
    * This takes either a postcode or an address string
    *
    */
    function plotAddress(address)
    {
      localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, 
        function() {

          if (localSearch.results[0])
          {     
            var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
            var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
            var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);
            var marker = new GMarker(point, addressMarkerOptions);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            map.setCenter(point, 15, G_NORMAL_MAP);
          }
          else
          {
            alert('address not found');
          }
        });

      localSearch.execute(address + ", UK");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent tutorial that will show you how to do this (and much more) is posted [here](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-ajax-php-mysql) ...

See Step 8 about adding a marker.

BTW you are using the old version / now deprecated of Google Maps API ...you should upgrade to [V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker).

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getLatLng().lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getLatLng().lng();
```

Comment: Not any more :-) In API 3.7 the calls are `marker.getPosition().lat()` and `marker.getPosition().lng()`